# How to perform a three-way (binary factors) between-subjects ANOVA with main effects and all interactions in R

Tags: r, anova

The study randomized participants by Source (Expert vs Attractive) and by Argument (Strong vs Weak), were categorized into Monitor type (High vs Low). I want to test the significance of the main effects, the two-way interactions, and the three-way interactions of the following dataframe - specifically,

Main effects = Self-Monitors (High vs. Low), Argument (Strong vs. Weak), Source (Attractive vs. Expert)

Two-way interactions = Self-Monitors*Argument, Self-Monitors*Source, Argument*Source

Three-way interactions = Self-Monitors*Argument*Source

This is the code:

```
data<-data.frame(Monitor=c(rep("High.Self.Monitors", 24),rep("Low.Self.Monitors", 24)),
                 Argument=c(rep("Strong", 24), rep("Weak", 24), rep("Strong", 24), rep("Weak", 24)),
                 Source=c(rep("Expert",12),rep("Attractive",12),rep("Expert",12),rep("Attractive",12),
                          rep("Expert",12),rep("Attractive",12),rep("Expert",12),rep("Attractive",12)),
                 Response=c(4,3,4,5,2,5,4,6,3,4,5,4,4,4,2,3,5,3,2,3,4,3,2,4,3,5,3,2,6,4,4,3,5,3,2,3,5,5,7,5,6,4,3,5,6,7,7,6,
                            3,5,5,4,3,2,1,5,3,4,3,4,5,4,3,2,4,6,2,4,4,3,4,3,5,6,4,7,6,7,5,6,4,6,7,5,6,4,4,2,4,5,4,3,4,2,3,4))
data$Monitor<-as.factor(data$Monitor)
data$Argument<-as.factor(data$Argument)
data$Source<-as.factor(data$Source)
```

I'd like to obtain the main effects, as well as all two-way interactions and the three-way interaction. However, if I type in `anova(lm(Response ~ Monitor*Argument*Source, data=data))` I obtain:

```
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: Response
               Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value    Pr(>F)    
Monitor         1  24.000 24.0000 13.5322 0.0003947 ***
Source          1   0.667  0.6667  0.3759 0.5413218    
Monitor:Source  1   0.667  0.6667  0.3759 0.5413218    
Residuals      92 163.167  1.7736                      
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

and if I enter `summary(aov(Response ~ Monitor*Argument*Source, data=data))`

```
Call:
lm.default(formula = Response ~ Monitor * Argument * Source, 
    data = data)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.7917 -0.7917  0.2083  1.2083  2.5417 

Coefficients: (4 not defined because of singularities)
                                                   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                                          3.4583     0.2718  12.722  < 2e-16 ***
MonitorLow.Self.Monitors                             1.1667     0.3844   3.035  0.00313 ** 
ArgumentWeak                                             NA         NA      NA       NA    
SourceExpert                                         0.3333     0.3844   0.867  0.38817    
MonitorLow.Self.Monitors:ArgumentWeak                    NA         NA      NA       NA    
MonitorLow.Self.Monitors:SourceExpert               -0.3333     0.5437  -0.613  0.54132    
ArgumentWeak:SourceExpert                                NA         NA      NA       NA    
MonitorLow.Self.Monitors:ArgumentWeak:SourceExpert       NA         NA      NA       NA    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.332 on 92 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.1344,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.1062 
F-statistic: 4.761 on 3 and 92 DF,  p-value: 0.00394
```

Any thoughts or ideas?

*Edit*
[image: Picture of the data]

Comment: It seems like with `summary(aov(Response ~ Monitor*Argument*Source, data=data))` you got exactly what you wanted. I assume the `NA`s are due to not enough degrees of freedom to estimate the desired effects. If you specify some more (how many subjects in each condition) or give a reproducible example it would help.

Comment: @GioraSimchoni The code for the dataset is there.

Answer (score 0):

Your data isn't well randomized as you say. In order to estimate a three-way interaction you'd have to have a group of subjects having "Low", "Strong" and "Expert" combination of levels of the three factors. You do not have such a group.

Look at:

```
table(data[,1:3])
```

For example.

Comment: Sorry Giora, but that's the question in the textbook Designing Experiments and Analyzing Data (p. 397). =/

Comment: The question has a problem... High Self Monitors always "come with" Strong Arguments - therefore no sufficient variation. You can change this though if it's a dummy dataset: rep(level1, 24) then rep(level2, 12) then rep(level3, 6), for each of the levels.